# Sending and receiveing UDP on the same port

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I use `X-Plane` and it send its output UDP data to `127.0.0.1:49000`. The problem rises when my application is supposed to listen to the same port to receive data via `boost::asio`.

I used the boost sample code at [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html) and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html).

```
// at main function:
udp_server server(49000);

// class implementation:
class udp_server
{
public:
    udp_server(int port) :
        io_service(),
        socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)) // Exception occurs here
    {
        start_receive();
        udp_thread = std::thread([this](){io_service.run();});
    }

    void start_receive()
    {
        socket_.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
            boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    // ...

    std::thread udp_thread;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket socket_;
    udp::endpoint remote_endpoint_;
    boost::array<char, 5000> recv_buffer_;
};
```

When I run the code, I receive an exception at the initialization of the socket:

> bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

It make sense, because `X-Plane` is writing at this port and I read from the same port. Both of us are occupying the same port. Is there any way to overcome this problem? If not, does it mean that two application at the computer cannot transfer message via `UDP`?

Answer (score 1):

> It make sense, because X-Plane is writing at this port and I read from the same port.

X-Plane is sending *from* that port and receiving *to* that port. It will write datagrams to (and receive datagrams from) whatever port the programs it has to talk to are receiving on and sending from.

> Both of us are occupying the same port. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Yes, pick a different port to send *from* and receive *on*.

> If not, does it mean that two application at the computer cannot transfer message via UDP?

They certainly can. Typically, one side picks a well-known port that it sends from and receives on. The other side uses a random port that it sends from and receives on, sending to and receiving from the well-known port.

So the flow is:

1. X-Plane always binds to a well-known port, 49,000.
2. You pick a random port, say 31,020. You bind to that port.
3. You send a datagram from port 31,020 to port 49,000, since that's X-Plane's well-known port.
4. X-Plane receives a datagram from port 31,020 to port 49,000, the port it is bound to. X-Plane notes that the datagram came from port 31,020.
5. X-Plane sends a response to port 31,020, the port your program is listening on from port 49,000, the port it is bound to and sends from.
6. Your program receives a datagram from port 49,000 to port 31,020, the port it is listening on.
7. Your program knows this is a response from X-Plane because it came from port 49,000.

Comment: `You pick a random port, say 31,020. You bind to that port`, Now I got the point. Could you please advise how to bind port in the code above? my search on google brings `boos::bind` which is irrelevant.

Comment: @Danze You probably don't have to do anything. If you don't `bind` to a port, the implementation will pick a random "ephemeral" port. If you have to specify a port, specify zero.

Comment: If I set `port=0`, then how should I tell `boost::asio` that the source is `:49000`? How will it find the source?

Comment: It doesn't need to find the source. You just send a datagram to 49,000 and the X-Plane server will send a reply to your source port, whatever it is. You don't need to know the source in order to receive a datagram -- if you did, how could X-Plane work? It has no idea who is going to send to it.